# Objective-C drawRect Custom RGB Fill Color

Tags: objective-c, rgb, uicolor, cgrect

I'm trying to fill a circle in Objective-C with a custom RGB color.  Here is my `drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:10.0 green:131.0 blue:254.0 alpha:1.0];

   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);

   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
   CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, [ball getRect]);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Whenever I specify anything in place of `[color CGColor]` like `greenColor` it works fine, but with the above code nothing gets rendered (an invisible object).  I know it is moving around the page because my update method is `NSLog`'ing a string for every update.

So, I want to fill and get the outer line of the circle to be the specified RGB color above.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha]` accept values between 0.0 to 1.0 ([Apple Docs Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:)) try changing the code like this:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:131.0/255.0 blue:254.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for each parameter in this method call:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0 green:131.0 blue:254.0 alpha:1.0];
```

should be between 0.0 and 1.0.